# How can I replace this data in between certain delimiter with Notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of data in this format

```
0000000000000000|000|000|00000|000000|CITY|GA|123456|8001234567
```

I need to replace the last piece of data with the word N/A so there is no phone number in the list.

```
0000000000000000|000|000|00000|000000|CITY|GA|123456|N/A
```

Thank you for the assistance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and fastest solution for that would be to search for

```
[^|\r\n]+$
```

and replacing all with `N/A`.

**Explanation:**

`[^|\r\n]+` matches one or more characters except `|` or newlines, and `$` makes sure that the match only occurs at the end of a line.

Comment: Certainly the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Do a find/replace, with the mode set to "Regular expression".

Find:

`(.*)\|[0-9]*`

Replace:

`\1|N/A`

Comment: This wont work because all those 0's are replaced data. Such as their name,username,ip, email, and etc. I didn't want to release that information to the public if you understand.

Comment: Yes, it just added N/A to the end of the line, with the phone number still there.

Comment: Did you incorrectly provide the line syntax? Is there a pipe at the end of the line you didn't include?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone numbers contain any non-numeric characters (such as periods, hyphens, spaces, etc.), then I would recommend the following adjustment to the regex given by @Bitwise:

```
(.*)\|(.*)$
```

Also, in Notepad++, the backreference syntax is not

```
\1
```

but rather

```
$1
```

which means your replace string will actually be

```
$1|N/A
```

Comment: I stand corrected. I actually tried \1 to begin with and it didn't work for me the first time. Good to know!

Comment: `\1` is the very old way, Npp use `$1` for a while now. `\1` is reserved for backreference in the regex itself, not for the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?!.*\|)(.+)
```

to mark the end of the line.
In Notepad++ you can use the search and replace (regex) function.